# CMD is not recognized python modules as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install any module with `pip install` the cmd/vscode return this message (I tried it with different ones)

```
C:\>pip install solc-select
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: solc-select in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (0.2.1)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

But when I try to run the module's code I get this issue:

```
C:\>solc-select use 0.8.7
'solc-select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've reinstalled my Python 3 and pip as well.

```
Python 3.10.5
C:\>pip --version
pip 22.1 from C:\Users\Jester\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

I'm facing this issue on Windows 10 x64 and I've added Python and pip folder/file to my system variables.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://github.com/crytic/solc-select#unsupported-platform-on-windows) ? _...Windows is currently in beta ... pip install solc-select==1.0.0b1_

Comment: yes, I did. Solc-select was the latest module that I tried to install/use, but I'm getting this issue for other modules as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with a virtual environment. To do that, take the following steps:

- In VScode (or a separate commanpdrompt screen), make sure you are in your working folder.
- Initialise a virtual environment with the command `python -m venv venv`. This will create a folder 'venv' in your working folder
- Activate your virtual environment with `bin\venv\activate`, you should now see `(venv) - C:/path/to/working/folder` in your command prompt.
- Install the module that you want, using your virtual environment with `pip install sold-select`